# Filtering operation on a response I get from retrofit 2 with rxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, observable

If I'm using retrofit with a rxjava converter to get the response, how and where can I filter the results (into say a List<> of users for example whos property `boolean paidDues = true`)?

```
Observable<User> observable = userService.me();
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() { // handle completed }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) { // handle error }

    @Override
    public void onNext(User user) { // handle response }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Filter:

```
Observable<User> observable = userService.me();
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.filter(new Predicate<User >() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(@NonNull final User user) throws Exception {
            return user.hasPaidDues(); // or something like this
        }
    })
.subscribe(...);
```